# Django 2.1.2: Generic detail view SchoolDetailView must be called with either an object pk or a slug in the URLconf

Tags: python, django

I am new in django and didn't understand what is pk or slug. What is going on?

models.py:

```
class School(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    principal = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=256)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Template Page:

```
<a class="navbar-brand" href="{% url 'basic_app:list'%}">Schools</a>
```

urls.py:

```
path('',views.SchoolDetailView.as_view(),name='list'),
```

views.py:

```
class SchoolDetailView(DetailView):
    context_object_name = 'school_detail'
    model = models.School
    template_name = 'basic_app/school_detail.html'
```

Comment: Your confusion seems deeper than that; you're mixing up details and lists. Do you want a list of all schools, or the detail of a single school? But if you don't understand pks or slugs then you have clearly not read the tutorial, so you should go and do that straight away before doing anything else.

Comment: i want list of all schools

Comment: So why have you used a DetailView instead of a ListView?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Detail view is used for fetching detail of a particular object. Inorder to do that you have to pass pk in your url.

```
urlpatterns = [
path('<int:pk>/', SchoolDetailView.as_view(), name='school-detail'),
```

]

If you want to display the list of object use ListView

Comment: can you tell me how to pass pk in url, Thanks

Comment: you have to pass this pk in your template url as well

Comment: Thanks I get it now